# Перенос строки в сообщении Bot Telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Аяксом выполняю простой скрипт:

```html
<?php 
require_once "connection.php";

$id = trim($_REQUEST["id"]);
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
$query = "SELECT A.car_numb, A.ttn, A.cargo, A.weight, T.telega_token, T.telega_chat_id FROM accounting_entry AS A 
LEFT JOIN contragents AS T ON (A.id_to = T.id_contr)
WHERE id=" . $id;
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
if ($result) $row_rec = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$token = $row_rec[4];
$chat_id = $row_rec[5];
$txt = $row_rec[0]."%2F".$row_rec[1]."\r\n".$row_rec[2]."\n".$row_rec[3];
$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");
if($sendToTelegram){
    echo "Запись №".$id." отправлена.";
} else {
    echo "Чет сломалось и не отправляется.";
}

?>
```

Результат в сообщении выглядит так:
AA8827TM/539138__Popcorne/n24200
Помогите перенести строку.

Comment: у вас и правда вот такое форматирование кода  в проекте?

Comment: `fopen` несколько необычно видеть для отправки хттп запроса, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось вставив `"%0A"`.

```
$txt = $row_rec[0]."%0A".$row_rec[1]."%0A".$row_rec[2]."%0A".$row_rec[3];
```

Comment: PHP_EOL в Вашем случае должен работать без проблем.